# How can I concatenate the string in the dictionary if the key is already present

Tags: c#

I am trying to concatenate the value in the dictionary if the key is already present. But how can I do that.

```
public class Test(SomeModel data)
{
   var sample = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   data.SomeProperty.ForEach(f => sample.Add(f.Id, f.Text)); 
}
```

I am getting an error while trying to add the text. Because I have same key. when found same key add the text. How to do that.
Thanks

Comment: look up the `string.Join()` method that should help you

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? Do you need to know how to check if dictionary contains key? Do you need to learn how to use `if` to perform check of condition? Are you looking into how to concatenate strings? It is somewhat hard to see what is issue with writing code that matches you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` method:

```
var sample =  data.SomeProperty
      .GroupBy(x => x.Id) 
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, x => string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Text)));
```

This will group the items based on `Id` and it will create a dictionary where the `Key` is `Id` and the `Value` is the corresponding text values of the `Id` concatenated in comma separated format.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the LINQ approach (i.e. the other answer), just because it seems more concise and readable. But I offer this as an alternative, and one I think is important to at least be aware of.

If for some reason you're in a different situation where that doesn't work for you (it seems obvious that in your original example, the LINQ approach should work), you can do it more explicitly. As an added bonus, this is probably (not certainly) slightly more efficient (*):

```
var sample = new Dictionary<int, string>();

data.SomeProperty.ForEach(f =>
{
    string newText = f.Text, oldText;

    if (sample.TryGetValue(f.Id, out oldText))
    {
        newText = oldText + newText;
    }

    sample[f.Id] = newText;
});
```

In any case, IMHO it's always good to know how to do something like this explicitly, as the "aggregate by key" scenario is fairly common and LINQ isn't always the most convenient way to do it, due to the lack of aggregators for other kinds of sequences.

Technically, you don't actually need to check the return result from calling `TryGetValue()` because the default value for the `string` type is `null` and concatenating `null` with another `string` instance is legal, where the `null` is treated as the empty string. But I like the explicitness of doing it this way, and in any case it saves a method call when the key's not present.

(*) LINQ is convenient, but that comes at a cost...here, while the `string.Join()` is probably better than string concatenation, you have the overhead of the grouping operation. Which winds up dominating the cost depends on your original data...if you have relatively few strings per key, concatenation is likely to be better, but if you have a large number of strings, the overhead of all those concatenations and temp strings can easily outweigh the overhead of the grouping operation.